# Read Data from a RDB file

Tags: c#, sql, readfile

I got a file that is in RDB extension. I need to get the data from this file to put data in a DataTable. But i don't know how to read data from RDB files. I didn't find informations on internet.

Please help me.

Have a great day.

Comment: Is it a Oracle file or from some other database?

Comment: I think it's from other database, It's look like this : https://ibb.co/0rF3DJh And after converting i want it look like this : https://ibb.co/hLqb9km.

Comment: I search and it's maybe an Oracle file, i can't tell. I can sen you the file if you want

Comment: Those a just filenames and doesn't tell me anything about the data inside the files.

Comment: The second image was the data inside the rdb file (first image), i get it by a software program converter. The data inside the rdb files is 8 sensors with many values and the date in the first column

Comment: The RDB extension has been used for a few different types of database so I'm not sure if the file came fro an oracle database (and which version of oracle).  To read the files it is binary and you need to use a connection string with the compatible driver.  If you have an old application check the connection string that was used.

Comment: i got the rdb file from a siemens automaton, i don't know anything more, i need to read theses data with a c# code

Comment: Looks like siemans has a rdb to csv converted.  See : https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf/ww/en/posts/rdb-file-to-csv-conversion-tool/182568/?page=0&pageSize=10

Comment: Yeah i know i see that, i use a similar application to convert the rdb file but i need to do this conversion in my project in C#, i need to do a code in c# which automatically
convert all the rdb files in a folder into csv files

Comment: You can run from process class.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=net-5.0  Yo ucan make a command line string with input and output filenames.  You can get the file names by getting a directory listing.

Comment: Actually i get all my files names with a foreach and a GetFileName in my directories. i don't understand what can i do with a command line, i'm lost

Comment: The link is running a command line like following : "argsecho.exe /a /b c:\\temp"  You have an application that would have a command line "dbd2csv.exe input_filename output_filename"  Where the input file name is the rdb file and the output filename is the csv file name

Comment: I'm sorry but i begin in C# code i'm litteraly lost. Someone give me this code in VB, this code convert rdb to csv like i want to do, but i don't know how to do the same thing in c#, here the code : https://codeshare.io/5gXgWR

Comment: You need to use the rdb2csv.exe utility.  You do not have a server to connect.

Comment: the rdb2csv.exe utility didn't work well for me, i didn't get the good values when i use this converter. The code i share with you work perfectly. I think i will give up it's to hard

Comment: It is easy.  Do you want results in c# or VB.Net?

Comment: I want to do this in C#, my project is in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put data into a DataTable as strings.  I didn't include any formatting that was in the original code.

```
public class Lecture
{
    public DataTable Lecture_RDB(string databaseName)
    {
        //Déclarartions des variables
        double mem_time, valeur_init;
        int ititre, k, l, nbligne;
        string entete = ";";
        string[] titre = new string[9];
        List<string> ligne = new List<string>();
        string ecriture = "";
        string indicetag = "";
        string destination = "";
        string mem_titre = "";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Col A", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Col B", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Col C", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Col D", typeof(string));


        //Déclarations base de données
        SQLite.SQLiteConnection SQLconnect = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection();
        SQLiteCommand SQLcommand;
        SQLiteDataReader SQLreader;

        try
        {
            //Connexion au fichier RDB
            SQLconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + databaseName + ";";
            SQLconnect.Open();

            //Creation Requete pour lecture en-tete
            SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand;
            SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM logdata";

            //Execution requete 
            SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (SQLreader.Read())
            {
                string[] row = SQLreader.Cast<object[]>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Si erreur pendant la lecture du fichier message
            Console.WriteLine("Error file reading : {0}.{1} Error", databaseName, ex.Message);
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks you it works, you are a genius ! But i got a last question, i didn't get the column header like in the second picture i send upper. I got all the value and it's perfect but i need the header column and I don't know where they are stored.

Comment: You just have to change the Column Add instructions.

Comment: Yes i'm stupid. I managed to sort my datatable by using a switch case and put it in a new datatable, but i now need to convert the Time_ms into a Date. Actually i'm trying this : 'DateTime.FromOADate(row[4] / 1000000).ToString;' But it doesn't work

Comment: Is database value a string or a Date?  I converted everything to a string which is not necessary.  So you can change Column type to a date.  dt.Columns.Add("Col D", typeof(DateTime));  then change data to objects object[] row = SQLreader.Cast<object[]>().Select(x => x).ToArray();  if you have numbers you would have to do the same.

Comment: I would like a function that convert my datetime in my datatable dt directly (return of the fonction). Not with a SQLreader. I want to take the value in a foreach and change the date value of the full datatable if it's possible

Comment: my date is a string like this actually : "43529266289.3287"

Comment: How come the link shows Date correctly?  You should store Date in Datatable as a DateTime object.  The format the results when you output the date.

Comment: Actually i got a Datable that looks like this after after doing my sorting : https://ibb.co/3kgM8NX Now i want to convert the Column Date in a Date like "05/03/2020 06:23:27". The format of the column is a string but if i put format in DataTime i can't put my value in the column

Comment: You should format the DataTable where you display the table.  How do you plan on displaying the table?

Comment: I'm not displaynig directly the table, i draw curve with this datatable, so i need the date to order my values

Comment: It's ok i found : i do it like that : 'double Date_ms = double.Parse(row[4].ToString());
                            DateTime date3 = DateTime.FromOADate(Date_ms / 1000000);'